# SMS does not send in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to open System default Messaging activity when clicking on a button. Here is my code:

```
smsUri = Uri.parse("tel:" + teacherPhone2);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, smsUri);
        intent.putExtra("address", teacherPhone);
        intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        startActivity(intent);
```

It works fine below MarshMallow. But in MarshMallow the app crashes when clicking that button. I have set the user-permission and also requested send sms permission. 
Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: Did you ask permissions in java code as well?

Comment: Put your crash log here.

Comment: Show the code where you have asked for permission

Comment: Your app doesn't need a permission to send SMS like that. Look in your logcat for the stack trace from the crash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173. I would guess that you're getting an `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

Check runtime permission before sending sms:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            int checkCallPhonePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RegistrationActivity.this,Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
            if(checkCallPhonePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RegistrationActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},SEND_SMS);
                return;
            }else{
                sendSms(mobile);
            }
        } else {
            sendSms(mobile);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

   if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }



public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

try this code

Comment: Hello! Please, format your answer appropriately (code, in your case). Thanks! :)

Comment: @BrunoPeres i think it's right format Thank you..! :-)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Add `SEND_SMS` permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

**2.** Request permission if not granted, send sms otherwise

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    int checkCallPhonePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RegistrationActivity.this,Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    if(checkCallPhonePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RegistrationActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},SEND_SMS);
        return;
    } else{
            sendSms(mobile);
    }
} else {
    sendSms(mobile);
}
```

**3.** Override onActivityResult in order to send sms after permission is granted

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    int checkCallPhonePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RegistrationActivity.this,Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    if(checkCallPhonePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        sendSms(mobile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be in MarshMallow **we can turn off and on** permissions for particular app. So check for permissions turned on or off before sending SMS.