# Run time permission in android version 7

Tags: android, permissions

I am using this code to get the run time permissions in android marshmallow but it is not working in android version 7 and above

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 123;
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE};

if (!hasPermissions(HomeActivity.this, PERMISSIONS)) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(HomeActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
}

public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions
{
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It might help responders if you format your code better and also explain how the code is failing.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782762/sms-does-not-send-in-marshmallow/43782856?noredirect=1#comment74607096_43782856 You got All run time Permissions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782762/sms-does-not-send-in-marshmallow/43782856?noredirect=1#comment74607096_43782856

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782762/sms-does-not-send-in-marshmallow/43782856?noredirect=1#comment74607096_43782856

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 123;
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE};

        if (!hasPermissions(HomeActivity.this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
                for (String permission : permissions) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

please use `requestPermision(permissions,PERMISSION_ALL);` instead of `ActivityCompat.requestPermision(context,permissions,PERMISSION_ALL);`